# Is there any query language or CLI tool to analyze encoded bitstream?

Tags: encoding, analysis

I'm learning codec, but most of the video analyzer tools are GUI and windows based. I'm wondering if there is a bitstream query tool to find the info I'm seeking for. Using SQL for example:

```sql
select top 5 macro_block
from video
where frame_number = 5
and frame_type = 'IDR'
and slice_number = 10
```

Or any CLI command tools could reach a similar goal?